# EF pulling out reference primary keys in a 1-M relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, relational

In a 1-M relationship, in the many side of the relationship I can pull out the Id of the parent item without doing another query using something like the following:

```
this.ParentReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value
```

But what I am wondering if there a similar way of pulling out the many ID's from the 1 without doing another query?

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless you eager-load (or project) the relationship.

When you load `this`, by itself, the EF loads all the data *from the table* which contains `this`. It doesn't `JOIN` in any other tables.

When you load `Parent`, the data containing the child IDs is in another DB table. So unless you tell the EF to load it, it will not `JOIN` in that other table.

So if you know that you will be needing the "child" IDs when loading `Parent`, you can eager load:

```
var p = Context.Parents.Include("Children").Where(p => p.Id == id).First();
```

...or project:

```
var q = from p in Context.Parents
        where p.Id == id
        select new
        {
            Parent = p,
            ChildIds = from c in p.Children
                       select c.Id
        };
```